# Почему один и тот же запрос к базе sqlite3 дает разный результат?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Во время ыполнения программы запрос к бд выдает ошибку

---

а через консоль запрос к этой же бд успешно выполняется

```
    cursor.execute("""update users set userorder={uord} where id={idd}""".format(idd=uid, uord="`{}:{}`".format(
                                                                                              str(country),
                                                                                              str(ipv))
                                                                                              )
               )
```

вот запрос в теле функции

```
cursor.execute('update users set userorder="us:6" where id="1290609049"')
```

вот запрос выполняю в консоли питона, просто подставив данные из функции
В консоли запрос выполняется без ошибок, а во время выполнения программ вылазит во такая ошибка

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: us:6

данные в консоли подставляю такие же  как и во время выполнения фунции.

Почему выдает ошибку и как это исправить?

Comment: Вместо cursor.execute сделайте просто print и увидите, что запросы совершенно не одинаковые

Comment: сдлал, вот результат:
update users set userorder=\`us:6\` where id=1290609049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой-то у вас зоопарк кавычек. Попробуйте так:

```
cursor.execute('update users set userorder="{country}:{ipv}" where id="{idd}"'.format(country=str(country), ipv=str(ipv), idd=uid))
```

Но лучше используйте параметризованные запросы из другого ответа.

Comment: зачем осознанно советовать автору код, подверженный `SQL Injections`?

Comment: Никогда так не делайте, и тем более, никому не советуйте.

Comment: Не могу удалить уже принятый ответ. Я просто с кавычками разобрался. Так то да, лучше параметрами.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте параметризированные запросы:

```
parms = (f"{country}:{ipv}", uid)
cursor.execute('update users set userorder=? where id=?', parms)
```

- во-первых это автоматически разрешит ваши проблемы с кавычками (если тип переменных будет соответствовать типу данных в таблице)
- во-вторых это обезопасит вас от [SQL injections](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
- в-третьих это скорее всего будет выполняться быстрее, т.к. не надо будет повторно парсить и оптимизировать запрос для разных значений